ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.5) on a geekom mini A5 with AMD Ryzen 7 7850H, wifi drops after 2 min and never connects,
ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.5) on a geekom mini A5 with AMD Ryzen 7 7850H, wifi drops after 2 min and never connects, i have to restart again after 2 min it drops.
Journalctl for network manager.
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2238] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.107
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2247] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2512] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2513] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2515] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2517] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2518] policy: set 'vodafoneB78E76' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2520] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 21 08:31:10 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684670.2836] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 21 08:31:12 geekompc NetworkManager[850]: <info>  [1713684672.1196] manager: startup complete

i have update rt8168 realtek patch but no luck.

any help would be appreciated.

my mistake, its 22.04

In terminal sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off See if it is power management issue
